# How to show UITableViewController as a UIPopover ViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I need to show a pop over with a tableview controller.

I am using the following code for presenting the pop over

func showPopOver() {

let secondStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle: nil)

```
viewObj =  secondStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
viewObj.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
viewObj.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400,500)

let popoverPresentationController = viewObj.popoverPresentationController
popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view //walletButton
popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, button.frame.origin.y+100, 0, 0)
presentViewController(viewObj, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

//MARK:- UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate methods... starts

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle{
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
    }
```

as like UIViewController then for now I am tried to load UITableViewController but its not working. UIPopover is displayed but not displayed tableview.

Please suggest me 
Thank you in-advance

Answer (score 5):

```
func showPopOver() {

    let tableViewController = UITableViewController()
    tableViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    tableViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 250)
    tableViewController.tableView=FontTable

    presentViewController(tableViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let popoverPresentationController = tableViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as! UIButton
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, sender.frame.size.width, sender.frame.size.height)
    popoverPresentationController?.delegate=self
    popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections=UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up
}

func prepareForPopoverPresentation(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController)
{
}

func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController)
{
}

func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.  I tried the above suggestion but not getting TableViewController for in my popover.  I am calling this  showPopOver() in viewDidAppear instead of the viewDidLoad now its showing TVC in my popover.

Comment: I am calling this  showPopOver() in viewDidAppear instead of the viewDidLoad along with the above UIPopover delegate methods then its showing TVC in my popover.